# Consumer.poll() returns new records even without committing offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If I have a `enable.auto.commit=false` and I call `consumer.poll()` without calling `consumer.commitAsync()` after, why does `consumer.poll()` return 
new records the next time it's called?

Since I did not commit my offset, I would expect `poll()` would return the latest offset which should be the same records again.

I'm asking because I'm trying to handle failure scenarios during my processing. I was hoping without committing the offset, the `poll()` would return the same records again so I can re-process those failed records again.

```
public class MyConsumer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, LogLine> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            for (ConsumerRecord record : records) {
                try {
                   //process record
                   consumer.commitAsync();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                /**
                If exception happens above, I was expecting poll to return new records so I can re-process the record that caused the exception. 
                **/
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The starting offset of a poll is not decided by the broker but by the consumer. The consumer tracks the last received offset and asks for the following bunch of messages during the next poll.

Offset commits come into play when a consumer stops or fails and another instance that is not aware of the last consumed offset picks up consumption of a partition.

[KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) has pretty extensive Javadoc that is well worth a read.

Comment: Makes sense. But the [poll() doc](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#poll(long)) says "The last consumed offset can be manually set through seek(TopicPartition, long) or automatically set as the last committed offset for the subscribed list of partitions"

Doesn't the latter do what my question is asking - which sets the consumed offset to be the last committed offset - which should cause `poll()` to not return new records if I never commit new offsets. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think the part of the documentation only refers to the starting point/offset of consumpation. So you either start anywhere by using seek or use the commited offset.

Comment: You mean it would use the committed offset only for the first time `poll()` is called?

Comment: @Glide Yes, it uses the stored offset only on 1st poll. You can also `seek` to the required offset before calling `poll`.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share some code how you can solve this in Java code.

The approach is that you poll the records, try to process them and if an exception occurs, you seek to the minima of the topic partitions. After that, you do the `commitAsync()`.

```java
public class MyConsumer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            List<ConsumerRecord<String, LogLine>> records = StreamSupport
                .stream( consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE).spliterator(), true )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );

            boolean exceptionRaised = false;
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, LogLine> record : records) {
                try {
                    // process record
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    exceptionRaised = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if( exceptionRaised ) {
                Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsetMinimumForTopicAndPartition = records
                    .stream()
                    .collect( Collectors.toMap( r -> new TopicPartition( r.topic(), r.partition() ),
                        ConsumerRecord::offset,
                        Math::min
                    ) );

                for( Map.Entry<TopicPartition, Long> entry : offsetMinimumForTopicAndPartition.entrySet() ) {
                    consumer.seek( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
                }
            }

            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup, you poll the messages again and again until you successfully process all messages of one poll.

Please note, that your code should be able to handle [a poison pill](https://www.confluent.de/blog/spring-kafka-can-your-kafka-consumers-handle-a-poison-pill/). Otherwise, your code will stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: As additional remark, the ``KafkaConsumer`` caches it's offset, even if no commit has been send. That's the reason, why the consumer polls new messages and not the old ones again. Re-initializing the consumer (``new KafkaConsumer()``) would as well be a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consumer will read from last commit offset if it get re balanced (means if any consumer leave the group or new consumer added) so handling de-duplication does not come straight forward in kafka so you have to store the last process offset in external store and when rebalance happens or app restart you should seek to that offset and start processing or you should check against some unique key in message against DB to find is dublicate